# Select record from Access table by comma separated value in single a TextBox

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I have a single TextBox and a search button. The user put multiple comma separated values in a single TextBox (ex. 111,222,333), which are stored in one column (ID), then fetch all the records in the grid view by an MS Access table.

Table name: mytable

Fields:

```
ID  name    phno
111 saket   8097626799
222 deepak  9167480458
333 abhi    9229457891
444 rajesh  9826789561
555 sudhir  9167849503
```

Output:

```
ID  name    phno
111 saket   8097626799
222 deepak  9167480458
333 abhi    9229457891
```

Comment: Please add the code you already have.

Comment: i dont have any code, please help

Answer (score 1):

The following does assertion on text within a text box, see comments. The variable whereCondition will contain the sample SQL statement if all assertion/validation passes.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string whereStatement = "";
    // ensure we have something to work with
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
    {
        // Are there commas
        if (textBox1.Text.Contains(","))
        {
            string textValue = textBox1.Text.TrimEnd();
            // make sure there is no trailing commas
            if (textValue.Last() != ',')
            {
                string[] parts = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
                int badCount = 0;
                int testValue = 0;
                // see if all values are int
                foreach (string item in parts)
                {
                    if (!int.TryParse(item, out testValue))
                    {
                        badCount += 1;
                    }
                }

                if (badCount == 0)
                {
                    string whereCondition = "ID = " + textValue.Replace(",", " OR ID = ");
                    whereStatement = string.Format("SELECT [Name], phno WHERE {0} FROM mytable", whereCondition);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // one id 
            whereStatement = string.Format("SELECT [Name], phno WHERE ID = {0} FROM mytable", textBox1.Text);
        }
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(whereStatement))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(whereStatement);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invald data");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I HAVE ANOTHER CODE
ITS WORKING
c# CODE

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.BindGrid();
        }
    }
    protected void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BindGrid();
    }

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    //string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\WebSite1\App_Data\MPHS.mdb";

    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
    {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            string resultCont = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text))
            {
                string[] contactNames = txtSearch.Text.Trim().Split(',');
                foreach (string cont in contactNames)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cont))
                    {
                        resultCont = resultCont + ",'" + cont + "'";
                    }
                }
                resultCont = resultCont.Remove(0, 1);
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Docnum IN (" + resultCont + ")";
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
            }
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                sda.Fill(dt);
                gvCustomers.DataSource = dt;
                gvCustomers.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```